# How to append database value into json field

Tags: postgresql

Employee Table:
ID      NAME      SALARY   BONUS      DETAILS
------------------------------------------------
1      ABC          10          1         {"DEPT":"A"}
2        PQR          20          1         {"DEPT":"A"}
3        STU          30          2         {"DEPT":"B"}
4        WER          40          2         {"DEPT":"C"}
5        UIYN         50          3         {"DEPT":"C"}

In above table want to append bonus field data into details field, whereas the details field is JSON data type. how to append data?

Answer (score 2):

`JSON` is not a good choice for updatable column, all updates will be done via additional type casts. For your case the code will be:

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET DETAILS = (DETAILS::JSONB || jsonb_build_object('BONUS', BONUS))::JSON;
```

or

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET DETAILS = jsonb_set(DETAILS::JSONB, '{BONUS}', BONUS::JSONB, TRUE)::JSON;
```

Comment: It's working only for those records having data into the details field. But if it does have any data, then it's not appending.